# parse dict key:value with pyspark (keys are not pre defined)

Tags: pyspark

I have a spark DataFrame that looks like :

```
[Row(id = '1', dictField={"keyA":"valueA","keyB":"valueB"}), 
 Row(id = '2', dictField={"keyC":"valueC","keyD":"valueD","keyA":"valueA"}),   
 Row(id = '3', dictField={"keyZ":"valueZ","keyA":"valueA"})]
```

I am trying to break it into the following format.

```
+---------+-----------+---------+
|       id|      key  |  value  |
+-------------------------------+
|        1|       keyA|  valueA |
|        1|       keyB|  valueB |
|        2|       keyC|  valueC |
|        2|       keyD|  valueC |
|        2|       keyA|  valueA |
|        3|       keyZ|  valueZ |
|        3|       keyA|  valueA |
```

Please note - the keys are not predefined/known.

Comment: Is that first list collected from an RDD?

Comment: It is a  DataFrame 
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dictField: string (nullable = true)

Comment: use maptype - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64444144/5108220

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If your column is in proper json format, then you can use json parser(get_json_object)
> to solve the problem.
>
> I have used udf and create code in spark scala. you can refer below
> code to solve the problem. I have used given schema  id: string
> (nullable = true) |-- dictField: string (nullable = true)

```
val df = Seq(("1","{\"keyA\":\"valueA\",\"keyB\":\"valueB\"}"),("2","{\"keyC\":\"valueC\",\"keyD\":\"valueD\",\"keyA\":\"valueA\"}"),("3","{\"keyZ\":\"valueZ\",\"keyA\":\"valueA\"}")).toDF("id","dictField")

+---+-------------------------------------------------+
|id |dictField                                        |
+---+-------------------------------------------------+
|1  |{"keyA":"valueA","keyB":"valueB"}                |
|2  |{"keyC":"valueC","keyD":"valueD","keyA":"valueA"}|
|3  |{"keyZ":"valueZ","keyA":"valueA"}                |
+---+-------------------------------------------------+

//create udf to parse the string into Array(String, String)
def parse_str(value:String) = {
  val values =  value.replace("{","").replace("}","").replace("\"","").split(",").map(_.trim)
  values.foldLeft(Array[(String,String)]()){
    case (acc, present) => 
      val Array(k, v) = present.split(",")(0).split(":")
      acc :+ (k,v)
  }
}

//register udf
val parsed_udf = udf(parse_str _)

//use above udf and explode the array
val result = df.withColumn("parse",explode(parsed_udf($"dictField")))

//select required value
result.select($"id", $"parse._1".as("key"), $"parse._2".as("value")).show()

+---+----+------+
| id| key| value|
+---+----+------+
|  1|keyA|valueA|
|  1|keyB|valueB|
|  2|keyC|valueC|
|  2|keyD|valueD|
|  2|keyA|valueA|
|  3|keyZ|valueZ|
|  3|keyA|valueA|
+---+----+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be a working solution for you, use MapType and then use Explode function which are available in Spark API Higher Order Function

**Create the Dataframe Here**

```
df_new = spark.createDataFrame([(str({"val1":"3", "val11":"31"})), (str({"val2":"4", "val22":"44"}))],T.StringType())
#OutPut
+----------------------------+
|value                       |
+----------------------------+
|{'val1': '3', 'val11': '31'}|
|{'val2': '4', 'val22': '44'}|
+----------------------------+
```

**Logic Here**

```
df_new = df_new.withColumn('col', F.from_json("value",T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.StringType())))
df_new = df_new.select("col", F.explode("col").alias("x", "y"))
df_new.show(truncate=False)
```

**Output**

```
+------------------------+-----+---+
|col                     |x    |y  |
+------------------------+-----+---+
|[val1 -> 3, val11 -> 31]|val1 |3  |
|[val1 -> 3, val11 -> 31]|val11|31 |
|[val2 -> 4, val22 -> 44]|val2 |4  |
|[val2 -> 4, val22 -> 44]|val22|44 |
+------------------------+-----+---+
```